# Using plt to display pytorch image

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch

`x` is the image, `y`is the label, and `metadata` are dates, times etc.

```
for x, y_true, metadata in train_loader:
  print(x.shape)
```

The shape returns:

```
torch.Size([16, 3, 448, 448])
```

How do I go about displaying x as an image? Do I use plt?

Comment: Hi there! you can use `matplotlib.pyplot` as you say, but for that you have to consider that you have `16x3xWxH` tensor,  you will have to iterate over first dimention and then transpose (using torch transpose you have to transpose 2 times to get `WxHx3 ` or only one to get `HxWx3 `) you alternatively can convert the tensor to numpy to transpose automatically all dimensions

Comment: also I remomend you to use plt.subplot(4,4,1) and then call a for with a `for idx,im in enumerate(x):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` is not a single image, but rather a batch of 16 different images, all of size 448x448 pixels.

You can use [`torchvision.utils.make_grid`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/utils.html#torchvision.utils.make_grid) to convert `x` into a grid of 4x4 images, and then plot it:

```py
import torchvision

with torch.no_grad():  # no need for gradients here
  grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(x, nrow=4)  # you might consider normalize=True 
  # convert the grid into a numpy array suitable for plt
  grid_np = grid.cpu().numpy().transpose(1, 2, 0)  # channel dim should be last
  plt.matshow(grid_np)
```